# Installing VPN connection and WiFi drivers on RHEL5

Tags: linux, installation, administration, rhel-5

In RHEL5,

1. How to establish a VPN connection,The details I get to connect the VPN are ipaddreess ,username/password
2. How to install WiFi drivers on RHEL5

Answer (score 0):

Too generic question. What chip has Wi-Fi? Look at >dmesg|less or less /var/log/dmesg or lspci or lsusb.